# How can I map Elements size and position to other Elements size and position on resize

Tags: javascript, html, css, vuejs3

So I've run into a problem trying to make objects on a image clickable.
I have an Image with 3 Objects that I want to link to 3 different pages / execute 3 different functions onclick.

Now my problem occurs when I resize my window. The Image having the following style to always display the objects, even if I resize the window and fill up the entire screen.

```
img {
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vh - 90px);
}
```

Since the objects are pretty big and when I resize, to let's say mobile view, the links will overlap and be bigger then the screen itself.

This is the current HTML Structure, which I can change.

```
<div>
    <img src="img/steintafelAussen.jpg" alt="Kircheneingang" />
    <div class="buttons">
        <button class="btn-1"></button>
        <button class="btn-2"></button>
        <button class="btn-3"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now my question is, would it be possible to kinda map the buttons sizes and positions to the image, that the rescale automatically, or would i need to use media-queries to achieve that?

I was thinking of tracking the initial scale of the image someone and applying that to the links with `transform: scale();`, maybe?

Could I use a transparent SVG that is placed over the image, has 3 objects with eventListeners instead of links?

Using JS is fine, since it is a vue 3 application.

Comment: Those buttons won't overlap when represented as they are, can we see also the CSS for all the related elements.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qeku8g54/ Would be an simplified version. I want these buttons to always be on their heads and the size of their heads for example. Doens't need to be 100% perfect, but should be close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by putting a SVG of the same size over the Image and adding eventListeners to the Paths of the Links. Leading to the following code:

```
.wrapper {
    aspect-ratio: 4 / 3;
    position: absolute;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 90px); /*Calc because my header and footer are 40px and 50px otherwise it would be 100vh*/
    margin: auto;
    width: auto;
    top: 40px; /*header is 40px*/
    right: 0;
    bottom: 50px; /*footer is 50px*/
    left: 0;
}
.img,
.overlay-svg {
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    width: auto;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

<div class="wrapper">
    <img
        class="img"
        src="/path/to/image"
    />
    <svg
        class="overlay-svg"
        viewBox="0 0 2049 1537"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
        <path
           class="btn-svg"
           d="M810 523V495.5L890 479.5H993.5L1090 495.5L1178 523V1311L787 1329.5L799.5 940.5L810 523Z"
        />
        <path
            class="btn-svg"
            d="M1461 672L1808 585L1832 1537H1471.5L1461 672Z"
        />
        <path
            class="btn-svg btn-lamp"
            d="M481 567L517 512L544 567L577 589.5L544 699L506.5 739.5L466 690L451 579L481 567Z"
        />
    </svg>
</div>
```